# Can't import module createChart from lightweight-charts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, syntax-error, javascript-import, lightweight-charts

Was following the documentation for lightweight charts and tried creating my first chart in Node.js on repl. I have the package.json with lightweight charts and ran `npm install lightweight-charts` in the repl shell and downloaded lightweight charts. Yet when I run the code I get this error:
`SyntaxError: Named export 'createChart' not found. The requested module 'lightweight-charts' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.`

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `LightweightCharts.createChart(...)` instead

Comment: just gives me an unexpected token error and points to the period after LightweightCharts

Answer (score 0):

Here's an entire test page.
Pay attention to the 1st script that loads the library (once compiled with `npm run build`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Debug page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.development.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <div id="container1"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.body, { width: 400, height: 300 });
        const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();
        lineSeries.setData([
            { time: '2019-04-11', value: 80.01 },
            { time: '2019-04-12', value: 96.63 },
            { time: '2019-04-13', value: 76.64 },
            { time: '2019-04-14', value: 81.89 },
            { time: '2019-04-15', value: 74.43 },
            { time: '2019-04-16', value: 80.01 },
            { time: '2019-04-17', value: 96.63 },
            { time: '2019-04-18', value: 76.64 },
            { time: '2019-04-19', value: 81.89 },
            { time: '2019-04-20', value: 74.43 },
        ]);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```